# Erro de verificação (if)

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para enviar vídeos para um banco de dados, para isto, também, quero que envie materiais complementares no mysql.

Dentro do form do html, encontra-se:

```
<div class="form-group ml-0 pl-0 mt-4">
          <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Enviar material complementar (opcional)</label>
          <input type="file" name="arquivo">
```

Onde é o input para enviar o arquivo.

Este formulário envia para registrar_video.php;

```
<?php
include("conexao.php");

$nome_video = $_POST['nome_video'];
$disciplina  = $_POST['disciplina'];
$link_video  = $_POST['link_video'];
$coment_video  = $_POST['coment_video'];
$arquivo = $_FILES["arquivo"];

if(!isset($arquivo['arquivo'])){

    $extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['arquivo']['name'], -4)); //pega a extensao do arquivo
    $novo_nome = md5(time()) . $extensao; //define o nome do arquivo
    $diretorio = "upload/"; //define o diretorio para onde enviaremos o arquivo
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome); //efetua o upload

    $sql_logar = "INSERT INTO video_monitor (titulo_video, disciplina, link_video, coment_video, arquivo, data) 
    VALUES('$nome_video', '$disciplina', '$link_video', '$coment_video', '$novo_nome', NOW())";
    $exe_logar = mysqli_query($conection, $sql_logar) or die (mysqli_error($conection));
  } 
  if(!empty($arquivo['arquivo'])){
$sql_logar = "INSERT INTO video_monitor (titulo_video, disciplina, link_video, coment_video, arquivo, data)
VALUES ('$nome_video', '$disciplina', '$link_video', '$coment_video', 'Nenhum arquivo', NOW())";

$exe_logar = mysqli_query($conection, $sql_logar) or die (mysqli_error($conection));
  }

?>
```

O erro está que, mesmo selecionando ou não um arquivo, ele está utilizando o if:

```
   if(!isset($arquivo['arquivo'])){
```

Sendo que, caso o usuário não enviar um arquivo ele teria que ir para o if:

```
   if(!empty($arquivo['arquivo'])){
```

Como posso fazer para solucionar o problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na documentação [PHP: Upload de arquivos com o método POST](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php) está escrito:

> Se nenhum arquivo for selecionado em seu formulário, o PHP irá
> retornar `$_FILES['userfile']['size']` como 0, e
> `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']` como "none" (nenhum).

Isso significa que `$_FILES['arquivo']` sempre estará inicializado e ao testar `!isset($_FILES['arquivo'])` independente do usuário ter ou não enviado um arquivo o resultado será `true`.

Para verificar se o arquivo foi enviado mediante a envio por HTTP POST use a função `is_uploaded_file()` com argumento `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']` cujo é o nome temporário com o qual o arquivo enviado foi armazenado no servidor.

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'])){
  //...Aqui vai o código caso tenha sido feito o upload do arquivo
} else {
  //...Aqui vai o código caso Não tenha sido enviado um arquivo
}
```